Using HTML in JavaScript
I was able to easily add text to my project using the following code:


const loadingText = $('#loading-text');
const text = "Your first sentence here"; // Your first sentence here

let i = 0;

const interval = setInterval(() => {
  if (i === text.length) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  } else {
    loadingText.text(loadingText.text() + text[i]);
    i++;
  }
}, 100); // Speed of animation (adjust as needed)
#loading-text {
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 20px auto;
            width: 50%;
            opacity: 1;
        }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loading-text"></div>



Now the question that has come to me is, is there a way to display such text as HTML without tags (of course with the tag effect on the text)?
For example something like this:
const text = "lorem rerum <b style=\"color:#f00;\">aperiam</b> maxime reiciendis";

In the text above, the word (aperiam) is placed between the  tag and I have also given it a linear style.
By placing the above line in the text code, it is printed as follows:
lorem rerum <b style="color:#f00;">aperiam</b> maxime reiciendis

Is there a way to display the output as HTML?

Edit:
I have already tried .html() and it prints the tag inside the text for me.
I want the effect of the tag to be on the sentence, but the tag itself should not be printed.

Use .html() instead of .text()

That's usually one of the first jQuery methods people learn, it's really surprising you don't know about it.

Hello, I tried this before, and when it reaches the HTML tag, the code starts printing unintelligible expressions.

Ah, the problem is that you're adding things one character at a time. That won't work when you have tags, since you need the whole tag.

I searched a lot, I tried many methods but I couldn't get any answer! Is such a thing possible or not?

Does this answer your question? What is the difference between jQuery: text() and html() ?

You can't add HTML one character at a time, since you need the <b> tag
Instead of a single string, make text an array of strings, so you can wrap tags around each character to add the style and color.
This works for tags that just add character style, since you get the same result wrapping each character with the tag as wrapping the tag around the whole string. It won't work for more complex HTML like links.


const loadingText = $('#loading-text');
const text = ["l", "o", "r", "e", "m", " ", "r", "e", "r", "u", "m", " ",
  '<b style="color:#f00;">a</b>', '<b style="color:#f00;">p</b>', '<b style="color:#f00;">e</b>', '<b style="color:#f00;">r</b>', '<b style="color:#f00;">i</b>', '<b style="color:#f00;">a</b>', '<b style="color:#f00;">m</b>',
  " ", "m", "a", "x", "i", "m", "e", " ", "r", "e", "i", "c", "i", "e", "n", "d", "i", "s"
];

let i = 0;

const interval = setInterval(() => {
  if (i === text.length) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  } else {
    loadingText.html(loadingText.html() + text[i]);
    i++;
  }
}, 100); // Speed of animation (adjust as needed)
#loading-text {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loading-text"></div>




As @Barmar said, you should use $().html() instead of .text(). But even so, you should invest a little more effort into the character incrementing. Currently I am spelling out each character of each html tag that I am inputting. Ideally each tag should be treated as a whole and should not even be counted as a character.
So, the following can only be a rough starting point:


const loadingText = $('#loading-text');
const text = 'Your first <b style="color:red">sentence</b> here'; // Your first sentence here

let i = 0;

const interval = setInterval(() => {
  if (i === text.length) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  } else {
    loadingText.html(text.slice(0,++i));
  }
}, 100); // Speed of animation (adjust as needed)
#loading-text {
            font-size: 24px;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 20px auto;
            width: 50%;
            opacity: 1;
        }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loading-text"></div>




Did you notice that the < character appears for a moment, and then there's an extra delay before it starts showing sentence?

Of course I noticed. You were right in saying that it is not really possible to do with html code, but my version will at least not garble up the code completely. I already mentioned in my answer that the tags should ideally be skipped and not be treated like letters of the sentence.

And of course, that's the tricky part of the whole thing. You really need an HTML parser that handles it at a higher level.

Try using $().html() instead of using .text() because we cant add one character at a time in HTML

I suggested this in a comment, it didn't work.
